# Two native AIR windows from a single AIR app?

Tags: air, actionscript-3

I'm building in FlashDevlop as pure AS3.

I'm looking at building a kiosk that uses two screens. Its used to administer tests. So one screen has the test, second the controls for admin the test. I have played with wide app but its not very elegant and I really would like both screens to run full screen on each screen. Is it possible to have one air app spawn two native air windows? A secondary question is it possible to detect multiple screens and target a screen to full screen to? Even something as simple as checking the window size to detect would work, im just not sure I can move and if the low level api will fullscreen on that screen. I could not find any examples of this in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What docs did you look into? I found it right away.

You'll need the [Screen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Screen.html) class if you want information on the screens that are connected to the PC. And here's some [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a47e0-8000.html) on using it.

To create new windows, just instantiate a new [NativeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html) class and call activate() on it when you're done configuring.

There's a lot of other useful stuff for you in the flash.display package. All the AIR stuff is marked with a little AIR icon. I have to admit that it would have been easier to find if they had put these classes in a separate AIR package.